# How to convert SHP/POSTGIS data into x, y, z, "cost" data?

Tags: postgis, convert, coordinate-system

Is there a way to convert a line layer (shp or PostGIS) data into (x, y , z, cost) i.e. (From_node, To_node, optional_Elevation, Cost/Weight) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some additional information would be useful to find out exactly how your data looks like and what you are trying to get out of it. The following statement might be a start:

```
SELECT startpoint(the_geom), endpoint(the_geom), z(endpoint(the_geom)), 
length(the_geom) FROM test_lines;
```

I didn't know where you want the elevation to be measured, so I took the z value at the end point for now.

*Update Jul 31*:

```
SELECT startpoint(the_geom), endpoint(the_geom), elevation, cost 
FROM test_lines;
```

*Update Aug 1*:

In OGR, a [LineString object](http://gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLineString.html) has similar functions StartPoint() and EndPoint().

Comment: the elevation and cost/weight are just stored in fields

Comment: startpoints and endpoints are the segment ends

Comment: are you assuming that startpoint and endpoints are separate fields?

Comment: startpoint() and endpoint() are both functions that accept lines as an input.

Comment: Awesome, now do you know of a way to do this in OGR/GDAL?

Comment: in OGR, a LineString object http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLineString.html has similar functions StartPoint() and EndPoint()